# Setting leftBarButtonItem not working

Tags: ios, swift

I haver a ViewController in which I'm trying to override the default back button with a custom one. Here is my code:

```
let myBackButton:UIButton = UIButton.init(type: .custom)
myBackButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backClicked), for: .touchUpInside)
myBackButton.setTitle("Back Plz", for: .normal)
myBackButton.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
myBackButton.sizeToFit()

let myCustomBackButtonItem:UIBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: myBackButton)
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = myCustomBackButtonItem
```

This is not working (I'm still seeing the default back button in the navigation bar). I also tried setting 'backBarButtonItem' and setting 'hidesBackButton = true' and neither worked.

Not sure if it's relevant but this ViewController is being "Push"ed from an embedded View Controller, so my general Storyboard setup is this:
Navigation Controller -> View Controller -> Embedded View Controller -> View Controller (where I'm working)

What am I doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: For an embedded viewController, you need to set the bar button in the viewController with the containerView not the embedded viewController

Comment: @Malik Good call - that fixed it